# Trying to toggle visibility of a dd element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of my dd element. For example, if I click one dt, it will show the dd. Then, if click the next dt, the last dd should hide and the current dd should show. Right now, I have to click on the same dt to show and hide it.

Here's the section of the html code :

```
<template id="todo">
    <div class="todo-item">
        <dt class="todo-id"></dt>
        <dt  class="todo-title"></dt>
        <dd class="todo-description hide"></dd>
    </div>
</template>
```

and here's the listener handling it:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.todo-item dt', function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().closest('.todo-description').toggleClass('hide');     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the other descriptions disappear, you need to add the `hide` class to them when you click on a `dt` element. By first finding the sibling `dd` element, we can exclude that from adding the `hide` class using `.not`; and then we can toggle the `hide` class on that element:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.todo-item dt', function(e) {
  let descr = $(this).siblings('.todo-description');
  $('.todo-description').not(descr).addClass('hide');
  descr.toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todo">
  <div class="todo-item">
    <dt class="todo-id">item #1 id</dt>
    <dt class="todo-title">item #1 title</dt>
    <dd class="todo-description hide">item #1 description</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="todo-item">
    <dt class="todo-id">item #2 id</dt>
    <dt class="todo-title">item #2 title</dt>
    <dd class="todo-description hide">item #2 description</dd>
  </div>
</div>
```